# In STS Spring Grails: Where to put a jar so it is in tomcat's shared/lib?

Tags: eclipse, grails, jar, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

I'm using Grails in STS Spring, and according to [the Xuggler docs](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler/downloads) I need to put the xuggler.jar file into tomcat's shared/lib dir.

Where is that directory for the run-app tomcat server in Grails/STS Spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't. Configuring the server or configuring Tomcat, is a separate activity from building and deploying your app. Tomcat is a container (web server) which can have many apps in it.

You only need to install the JAR in Tomcat's lib directory once, but you will build and redeploy your app to the server many, many times. If you want to include a JAR in your app (not in Tomcat) then you would do that in BuildConfig.groovy in grails-app/conf. But those jars get included in your application's WAR file, they do not go in Tomcat's lib directory.

Comment: I know how to deploy a jar into the app itself, either by adding it to BuildConfig or by manually copying it into the /lib dir.  Since xuggler contains JNI calls to native libs, you're supposed to deploy it into the container itself instead of the apps.  Just curious how to do that for run-app.  But I guess it doesn't matter since only 1 app runs at a time in the run-app server.